# How to log the files of the gradle copy method?

Tags: logging, gradle, copy, println

Is it possible with println inside the method `copy` to print all file names to the console. Or is there another option to print the copied files?

```
copy {
  from "${source}"
  into "${target}"
  include "foo"
  include "xyz"
  println ???
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
copy {
   from "${source}"
   into "${target}"
   include "foo"
   include "xyz"
   eachFile { println it.name }
}
```